# .net core dependency injection breaks with generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

Basically we have a Interface that takes another interface (constrained)
When you create a hard implementation of that interface through a base class, the conversion fails as there is no implicit conversion.

I know that was probably hard to follow so we've gone ahead and made the simplest .NET 6 console app possible to show this issue.

Definition:

```
public interface IClient { }

public abstract class ClientBase : IClient { }

public class Client : ClientBase, IClient { }

public interface IServer<TClient> where TClient : IClient { }

public abstract class ServerBase<TClient>
    : IServer<TClient> where TClient : IClient { }

public class Server : ServerBase<Client> { }
```

Console:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ConsoleApp;

public class Program
{
    public static IServiceCollection Services = new ServiceCollection();
    public static ServiceProvider Provider;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Services.AddSingleton<IClient, Client>();
        Services.AddSingleton<IServer<IClient>, Server>();

        Provider = Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var server = Provider.GetService<IServer<IClient>>();
    }
}
```

`Server` can be type casted to an `IServer`

`Client` can be type casted to an `IClient`

But you cannot implicitly type case a `Server` instance to an `IServer<IClient>` even though the base implementations all can be casted to those types.

I'm absolutely confused about this. We can fix it by changing DI to take an `IServer<Client>` but then one of our services which looks for ALL implementations of `IServer<IClient>` cannot work anymore since we are providing a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the base class is not `IServer<IClient>` but defined as `IServer<Client>`. Which cannot be implicitly converted. This is a common problem when using generics. :-(

This is a [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) problem. It will work when you define it with `out`:

```
public interface IServer<out TClient> where TClient : IClient
{

}
```

> Covariance enables you to use a more derived type than that specified by the generic parameter. This allows for implicit conversion of classes that implement covariant interfaces and implicit conversion of delegate types.

Comment: oh boy this is super close, now im just having trouble in my ACTUAL implementation that i dont understand. 

its telling me i have an invalid variance for some of my method stubs within the interface 

        bool GetData(out byte[] data, out TClient sendingClient); 

is not valid nor is List<TClient>

any ideas?